# Creating elements without using the basic elements

Tags: elements, nucleosynthesis

Have there ever been created an element in the history (I'm talking about the 20 well known synthetics element) without using any other of the available elements from the nature?

For example, [element 117](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ununseptium) is made from bot berkelium and calcium (both basic elements). So is it possible to create an element without other elements?

Comment: So you want to know if an element has been created from something like a molecule, as opposed to elements?

Comment: Thanks for edit.

If so there has been created an element from a molecule, is this molecule still from nature or not? 

All I want to know is, if it's possible to create a new element without "any help" from other elements at all

Comment: I don't think it's possible to create anything without help from elements. Where would the protons/neutrons/electrons come from, if not molecules or elements?

Comment: Perfect. That was the answer I wanted to hear.

Because I had a discussion with someone who believed it was possible, and I told the person the same thing too; how is it possible without using protons & neutrons & electrons from the nature and thereby using already available elements?

But I want to know Kyle... Do you have any overview about HOW elements has been created synthetic ? From which other elements I mean?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to understand your question, but one can generate particles out of "nothing", as long as energy is conserved. For example, electron positron pairs are produced in the vacuum spontaneously.

Answer (score 0):

it would not be possible to create a new element without the need for other elements, as any new element still requires protons, neutrons and electrons as everybody knows. even if it were made up of individual protons neutrons and electrons, the protons would be hydrogen nuclei so it would not count. I am not sure if there is a misunderstanding, but it is clearly not possible

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. So you are telling me, that even so it's possible, you will still have to use protons (which is hydrogen) and that will not count itself, because then we still have used something from the "nature" - right? :)

Comment: yes, but really it depends on the definition of 'natural'. everything anywhere must have come from 'nature' at some point. but if you mean an element made of 2 artificial elements, then their half lives are just too short to do anything with them.

Comment: Okay but the fact is, that you somewhere still need to use at least an atom from the nature to produce something new.. right? :)

Comment: yes, thats correct

Answer (score 0):

I would think that,theoretically, you can create nuclei without any "input" nuclei, for example, through "annihilation" of two energetic photons, where pairs of charged particles are created, but currently that seems impractical.

Comment: Okay, awsum. But you are still using something that already exists for that, which are "photons"... I was just wondering if you can create something new from the bottom , without using ANYTHING of all the elements that exists in the universe